# Text to speech doesn't seem to be working and there is no error message in logCat

Tags: android, text-to-speech

There appears to be something wrong with this code, each time its saying that I have not installed texttoSpeech on create and I have done, also when i click the start read button the application crashed with no error messages... So heres the code..

```
public class CBrecipeReader extends Activity{


public Cursor cursor;
CBDataBaseHelper data;
public static int ReadData = 1;
public TextToSpeech Speak = null;
public boolean SpeakInit = false;
public TextView Speech;
public TextView rowIDText2;
CBListAdapter adapter;
String RowID;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.texttospeech);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

Button StartSpeech = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startSpeech);
rowIDText2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rowID2);
Speech = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sayThis);

if (extras != null) {
    RowID = extras.getString("SELECTED3");
    rowIDText2.setText(RowID);
}

if (rowIDText2.getText() != ""){

    data = new CBDataBaseHelper(this);
    String s = rowIDText2.getText().toString();
    int ID = Integer.parseInt(s);
    data.open();
    Cursor cursor = data.fetchRow(ID);


if (cursor.moveToFirst()){ // data?

    Speech.setText(cursor.getString(1) + " " + cursor.getString(2) + " " + cursor.getString(3));
}

data.close();
}
//+ " " + cursor.getString(2) + "" + cursor.getString(3)
initSpeak();
speakButtons(StartSpeech);
}
protected void initSpeak(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(intent, ReadData);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    if (requestCode == ReadData){
        if (resultCode == Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS){
            Speak = new TextToSpeech(this, new OnInitListener() {

                public void onInit(int status) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                    SpeakInit = true;
                    if(Speak.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.UK) >= 0){
                        Speak.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                        Speak.setPitch(0.8f);
                        Speak.setSpeechRate(1.1f);
                    }
                    }
                }

            });
        }else {
            Intent installVoice = new Intent(Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installVoice);
        }
    }

}

protected void speakButtons(View view){
boolean diditwork;
try {
Speech = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sayThis);

if (Speak != null && SpeakInit){

    Speak.speak("test", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);


} else if (SpeakInit == false){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Text to speech Installed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}catch(Exception e){
    diditwork = false;
    String error = e.toString();
    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setTitle("darn");
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(error);
    d.setContentView(tv);
    d.show();
}
}




}
```

Comment: I would added some logging to give yourself feed back after each step, so you know where it is crashing and what the current values are when it does crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to be very similar to mine, the only difference I can see is

I call:

`Speak.speak("test", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);`

You call:

`Speak.speak("test", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);`

Comment: No its still displaying a Toast saying that there is not TTS Engine installed.. yet the first time i ran this code it did install it from the market.. and again still crashing when i click the button, im connecting in debugging mode to my computer not with diskdrive tho so it should see it, stumped

Comment: Is it "crashing" or not working?  Do you see the toast and then it crashes?  If you are debugging, then put a breakpoint in `onActivityResult` to see if it ever returns.  Can you uninstall what was installed from the market?

Comment: my goodness the whole time the error was to do with that my speakButtons method was protected!!!... thanks for help anyway :)